# Why can't I can't I use my Oracle user defined type like this?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql

In an Oracle package I have defined a type

```
type setTable is table of my_sets.pkey%type;
```

in the package declaration (the non-body part).  The `pkey` column referenced is a `number(38)`.  Then in a function in the package body I have

```
...
with d as (select column_value from table(sets)),
...
```

where `sets` is a parameter to the function of type `settable`.  This line fails to compile with the error 'ORA-22905: cannot access rows from a non-nested table item'.  What can I do to resolve this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The select statement is SQL not PL/SQL, and the SQL engine can only work with types defined on the server like this:

```
create type setObj is object (<attributes>);
create type setTable is table of setObj;
```

Comment: Just a small addition for Pip Falconer: DB defined type can be not only `object` but `table of...` or `varray` as well.

Comment: I mean would my original version work in 11g?  I'm sure yours will work everywhere.  I have two systems and my one *seems* to be compiling on one (which is 11g).

Comment: Oh right, no PL/SQL collections can't be used in a SELECT statement even in 11G - they just don't "exist" at the SQL level.